# Passing dropdown selected value as query string to URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, drop-down-menu, selected

On select event of a HTML dropdown value, I want to trigger being directed to a certain URL and that selected value being appended to the URL as query string. How to achieve that in javascript or jquery?

```
<select id="hospitalDropDown">
            <option>All Hospitals</option>
            <option>Dyer</option>
        <option>Carmel</option>
        <option>Indianapolis</option>
        <option>Beech Grove</option>
</select>
```

So if Dyer is selected, the result should be being directed to http://mysite.com/events.aspx?hosp=Dyer

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in jquery

```
$( '#hospitalDropDown' ).on( 'change', function( e ){
  document.location.href = "http://blah" + $( this ).val();
});
```

EDIT: changed "bind" to the more modern "on"

Comment: Thanks, you won't mind a little upvote then, trying to get some rep around here :-)

Comment: @Alex that was an old answer, these days I'd use .on instead of .bind

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the latest version of jQuery, you can attach an event handler using the [on() function](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$('#hospitalDropDown').on('change', function () {
    window.location.assign('http://mysite.com/events.aspx?hosp=' + $(this).val());
});
```

To see this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/73PEg/

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the advantage to using .on vs just $('#hospitalDropDown').change() ?

Comment: .change(), which is a shortcut for .bind('change') only attaches to currently loaded DOM elements. From the documentation: "The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object. As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers. For help in converting from older jQuery event methods, see .bind(), .delegate(), and .live()."

Comment: thank you for taking time to answer my question, I used the first answer though.